# Ubuntu 16.04 Django 1.11.5 virtualenv opencv

Tags: python, django, opencv, ubuntu, virtualenv

I'm new to Ubuntu, and also fairly new to web development, so I am hoping there is some obvious thing I am missing.

My problem is as follows: I have a box running Ubuntu 16.04 and I have my Django project with a virtualenv. With the virtualenv activated, I ran `pip install opencv-python`, and it seemed to work (all the files seem to be where I would think they need to be (`env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/{cv2,numpy}`).

But when I run `manage.py`, I get an error that traces back to `__init__.py` in the `opencv` package:

> ImportError: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

I get the same error when I run `python` interactively in the virtualenv and try to import cv2.

Is `.cv2` in the error a namespace? Is there an way I can get more information or do a python search for the namespace?

Comment: Please copy-paste the full traceback, instead of using an image: not everyone can see or read an image, and it's barely readable as is.

Comment: As the error suggest, you need the `libSM` library. Using `sudo apt-get install libsm6` may do the trick, or otherwise try `sudo apt-get install libsm-dev` and re-install OpenCV.

Answer (score 2):

Evert's comment was correct. I followed his steps and got a different, but similar, error. It turns out I had to install `libxrender1`.

Here are the steps I used:

1. activate my virtual environment
2. uninstall `opencv-python`
3. `sudo apt-get install libsm6`
4. reinstall `opencv-python`
5. `sudo apt-get install libxrender1`

Comment: Please update your answer to explain EXACTLY what steps you took, otherwise nobody else will be able to reproduce this. StackOverflow isn't a forum, it's a QA site, so don't treat answers as replies; They need to be complete.

Comment: If these were the steps that worked, please mark it correct.